# Map for Highmaps with England, Wales and Scotland etc

Tags: javascript, dictionary, highmaps

I'm looking for a map for Highmaps that includes England, Scotland and Wales (etc.) as seperate countries. At the moment I'm using the ultra hi-res miller map:
http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/

Or is there a simple solution to alter that map accordingly?

Comment: Can you provide a link for the one that you are using and indicate what is not right with it? For example, this one has the UK countries as separate countries http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/gb/custom/gb-countries

Comment: I used this one:
http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres3.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately highcharts with map v1.1.2 support only "[United Kingdom](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/all-maps#countries/gb/gb-all)" and "[United Kingdom countries](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/all-maps#countries/gb/custom/gb-countries)"